# JS-only properties on ember objects. MANDATORY_SETTER thing

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I tried building a time input component inspired by [google's timer](http://google.com/search?q=timer).

This is my version:

[image: My version here]

I know there are a ton of ways to do this, but this one puzzled me the most.

I chose to use an array to `shift()/push()` the last digit/new digit in place and keep the array `length <= 4`

#### Template:

```
{{input value=inputValue type="text"}}

<span {{bind-attr class="digits.3::placeholder"}}>{{digits.[3]}}</span>
<span {{bind-attr class="digits.2::placeholder"}}>{{digits.[2]}}</span>
<span {{bind-attr class="digits.2::grey"}}>h</span>

<span {{bind-attr class="digits.1::placeholder"}}>{{digits.[1]}}</span>
<span {{bind-attr class="digits.0::placeholder :last"}}>{{digits.[0]}}</span>
<span {{bind-attr class="digits.0::grey"}}>m</span>
```

#### Component:

```
App.TimeInputComponent = Ember.Component.extend(
  MAX_TIME: 99 * 60 + 59

  didInsertElement: () ->
    if @get('value')
      @set('inputValue', @formatValue(@get('value')))

  classNames: ['time-input-component']
  classNameBindings: ['focused:focused']

  digits: []

  keyUp: (e) ->
    code = e.which
    char = String.fromCharCode(code)
    return unless 48 <= code <= 57 or code == 8 or code == 9

    digits = @get('digits')
    if code == 8
      digits.shift()
    else if char.match(/[0-9]/)
      digits.pop() if digits.length >= 4
      digits.unshift(char)

    # Initial idea: NOT working
    @notifyPropertyChange('digits')
```

Did some lengthy debugging and found this:

Due to `MANDATORY_SETTER`, the call to `get()` looks only inside the object's `meta.values`, not in the properties themselves (`obj[keyName]`).

So just to test it, I did this to cause the values in the component's `this.digits[Ember.META_KEY].values` to update:

```
    @set('digits.0', digits[0])
    @set('digits.1', digits[1])
    @set('digits.2', digits[2])
    @set('digits.3', digits[3])
```

Is there a way around the 4 set() calls and still using a plain array?
Should I use an ArrayProxy instead? I wish I could use a plain array though, in this particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you find yourself needing to dig into Ember internals to understand what's going on, you've deviated from the elusive "Ember way" and Ember will just keep fighting you on it. As you've discovered, referencing specific elements in an array inside a template isn't something Ember really wants you to do.

Rather than continuing to think about digits as an array in your template, why not give the individual digits names like `hoursTensDigit`. Then you could either replace your sets with:

```
@set 'hoursTensDigit', digits.objectAt(3)
...
```

or add some computed properties to the component

```
hoursTensDigit: ( ->
    return digits.objectAt(3)
).property 'digits.@each'
...
```

You can keep referencing the individual digits everywhere else except your template (though you probably want to use `.objectAt(..)` instead of '.[x]'), and everything should work swimmingly. The computed properties, or putting all the sets inside an observer on 'digits.@each', will give you the most mileage once you start counting down the timer and such.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've actually tried that one before, but I wanted to try the approach I've described, just to see how it would work out. I wanted to avoid having a property per digit, mostly aesthetics.